# Trouble while converting datatable to nested json c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a SQL Table with values like:

```
 Main_group   Sub_group  CstCmpCode
 COMBO SET    DD-101       AH01
 COMBO SET    DD-102       AH01
```

I need to create nested json string like:

```
{
  "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
  "Main_Group": "COMBO SET",
  "sub_group": [
      {
         "Sub_Group": "DD-101",
      },
      {
         "Sub_Group": "DD-102", 
      }
    ]
}
```

My code as below for converting datatable to nested json string :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TallyWeb"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct Main_group, Sub_group, CstCmpCode from TlyStkSumm where CstCmpCode = @CstCmpCode";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CstCmpCode", CstCmpCode);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row = null;
foreach (DataRow rs in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
}
```

Pls. check in the above what i am going to wrong.

Thanks. 
Yogesh.Sharma

Comment: What output are you currently getting? some data? an error?

Comment: i am getting error : "Error converting value \"\u0004 Primary\" to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebService+SubGroup]\u0027. Path \u0027[0].Sub_group\u0027, line 1, position 48."

Comment: any one pls. help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need grouping on `Main_Group` and `CstCmpCode`, I would suggest you simple `Linq`to group and select in desired format and pass it to `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize it.

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => 
        new
        {
            Main_group = x.Field<string>("Main_group"),
            CstCmpCode = x.Field<string>("CstCmpCode")
        })
    .Select(x=> 
        new
        {
            Main_group = x.Key.Main_group,
            CstCmpCode = x.Key.CstCmpCode,
            sub_group = x.Select(s => new {Sub_Group= s.Field<string>("Sub_group") })

        } );

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedString = serializer.Serialize(results);
```

**Output :**

```
[{
    "Main_group": "COMBO SET",
    "CstCmpCode": "AH01",
    "Sub_group": ["DD-101 ", "DD -102 "]
}]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i need to display JSON Response as above

Comment: That's easy just modify Linq query to create an anonymous object with the name and value.

Comment: sorry for this comments but i am new in JSON as well as in C# langauage

Comment: the above answer is correctly match with my requirements i am really thanking you since two days i am posting new questions as i don't know what really needs to do. But, as your suggestion it is really help full for me and just suggest me where i needs to correction. so, i can correct it and mark his post as solved by Mr. Hari Prasad

Comment: @YogeshSharma try my updated code. It should generate what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answered and it will very help full for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col]);
```

Here you are trying to add different type of objects to this collection of yours. If all values can be stored as strings (I guess this is OK, because you are creating JSon object afterwards, try changing that line to:

```
 row.Add(col.ColumnName, rs[col].ToString());
```

Comment: showing error : "Error converting value \"\u0004 Primary\" to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebService+SubGroup]\u0027. Path \u0027[0].Sub_group\u0027, line 1, position 48."